# resource output value from one plan into another plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I have two plans, in which I am creating two different servers(just for example otherwise it's really complex). In one plan, I am outputing the value of the security group like this:

```
output "security_group_id" {
  value = "${aws_security_group.security_group.id}"
}
```

I have second plan, in which I want to use that value, how I can achieve it, I have tried couple of things but nothing work for me.

I know how to use the `output` value return by `module` but don't know that how I can use the `output` of one plan to another.

Answer (score 3):

When an output is used in the top-level module of a configuration (the directory where you run `terraform plan`) its value is recorded in the Terraform state.

In order to use this value from another configuration, the state must be published to a location where it can be read by the other configuration. The usual way to achieve this is to use [Remote State](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html).

With remote state enabled for the *first* configuration, it becomes possible to read the resulting values from the *second* configuration using [the `terraform_remote_state` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html).

For example, it's possible to keep the state for the first configuration in Amazon S3 by using a backend configuration like the following:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "example-s3-bucket"
    key    = "example-bucket-key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

After adding this to the first configuration, Terraform will prompt you to run `terraform init` to initialize the new backend, which includes migrating the existing state to be stored on S3.

Then in the *second* configuration this can be retrieved by providing the same configuration to the `terraform_remote_state` data source:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "example" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "example-s3-bucket"
    key    = "example-bucket-key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  # ...
  vpc_security_group_ids = "${data.terraform_remote_state.example.security_group_id}"
}
```

Note that since the second configuration is reading the state from the first it is necessary to `terraform apply` the first configuration so that this value will actually be recorded in the state. The second config must be re-applied any time the outputs are changed in the first.

Comment: what if I have local `state` file?

Comment: avoid local state files though

Answer (score 1):

For the `local` backend the process is same. In first step, we need to declare the following code snippet to publish the state.

```
terraform {
 backend local {
    path = "./terraform.tfstate" 
  }
}
```

When you execute `terraform init and terraform apply` command, please observe that in `.terraform` directory new `terraform.tfsate` file would be created which contains backend information and tell terraform to use the following `tfstate` file.

Now in the second configuration we need to use `data source` to import the outputs by using this code snippet

```
 data "terraform_remote_state" "test" {

 backend = "local"
  config {
    path = "${path.module}/../regionalvpc/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't wanna do local though.